# using pre defined mapper class in new mapper class jdbi sql fluent queries

Tags: java, sql, jdbi

How I can implement predefined mapper class of an class into the new mapper class of another class which have first class as object

```
public class Class2Mapper implements ResultSetMapper<Class2>
{
    public Class2 map(int index, ResultSet rs, StatementContext ctx)
    {
         Class2 myC2 = new Class2();
         //Do something to Map myC2.class1Object with rs 
         //Do some mapping with other variables of myC2
         return myC2;
    }
}
```

Assuming that `Class1Mapper` is already defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can a mapper inside another mapper also.

```
public class Class2Mapper implements ResultSetMapper<Class2> {
    private Class1Mapper class1Mapper;
    public Class2Mapper() {
        this.class1Mapper = new Class1Mapper();
    }
    public Class2 map(int index, ResultSet rs, StatementContext ctx)
    {
         Class2 myC2 = new Class2();
         class1 = class1Mapper.map(rs,ctx); // use this class1 object 
         //Do some mapping with other variables of myC2
         return myC2;
    }
}
```